# cakephp session not working after routing will be done

Tags: session, routes, cakephp-2.3

In my cakephp application , i just used the routing after that, in that routed page the cakephp session is not working...

This is my code:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'Organizations', 'action' => 'view', 'orgname' => $orgname));

Then in the Organizations/view, the cakephp session is not working...
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: I am also having same problem .Look like session is never started for routed urls.Did you get any solution ?

Comment: yes i got the solution...pls check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I just put the following code into my routed controller's action..

```
  App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
    $value_user_id = CakeSession::read('LoggedSessionUserId');
```

Then i got the session value successfully...